# Centos server network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, internet, centos

I have an old computer running Centos. Im using it to host a TeamSpeak 3 server.

The problem is that all internet access is blocked in my house as long as my server is connected to the internet.

As soon as i **unplug the cable** from the server PC, or turn it off, the internet is back on all other machines in my house and everything is normal.

Computers and phones within my home network are able to connect to the teamspeak server, but there is no internet access.

Im pretty new to Centos and Linux in general, but all ports necessary are opened....the only problem is that the server "kills" the internet..... what could be the problem?

And where should i start ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting your CentOS server is accidentally or misconfigured to use your home DSL-router's gateway IP address.  Root cause is DHCP settings. Possibly your IP address is statically configured. Show us output of `ifconfig -a` and `route -n` and compare the output to a functioning host on your network (IP address, default gateway).